# Matrix exponentiation without numpy

Tags: python, matrix

I need to write a function that performs the usual exponentiation of a matrix

```
def matrix_power(a, power):
    rows, columns = len(a), len(a[0])
    result = np.zeros((rows, columns))
    b = a
    for step in range(1, power):
        for i in range(0, rows):
            for j in range(0, columns):
                for m in range(0, rows):
                    result[i][j] += a[i][m] * b[m][j]
        a = result
    return result
matrix_power(matrix, 3)
```

But for some reason it gives a different answer from `np.linalg.matrix_power(matrix, 3)` What could be the problem?

Comment: I think it should be `if i != j` instead of `if i != J`

Comment: also it would help not to make mistakes if you used the same indices as in the definition (i, j, m)

Comment: @MarcIttel thanks for the comment, I changed the meaning of the question so that the problem is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> result = np.zeros((3, 3))
>>> result
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> a = result
>>> result[1][0] += 42
>>> result
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [42.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [42.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The problem in your code is that you are not copying `result` to `a` and when you later mutating `result` in the loop, you mutate `a` at the same time.

To make a copy, replace your assignment with this:

```
a = result.copy()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can I fix this moment?

Comment: i seem to understand, it's enough for me after `a = result`, and additionally add `result = np.zeros((rows, columns))`

Answer (score 1):

```
def matrix_power(a, power):
    rows, columns = len(a), len(a[0])
    result = np.zeros((rows, columns))
    b = a
    for step in range(1, power):
        result = np.zeros((rows, columns)) # reset result to all zeroes matrix here
        for i in range(0, rows):
            for j in range(0, columns):
                for m in range(0, rows):
                    result[i][j] += a[i][m] * b[m][j]
        
        a = result
    for val in result:
        print(val)
    return result
```